# stringFromDate and dateFromString sometimes return null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I simply have to format the date which comes in this format "2013:07:24 11:05:04" into this format "24-lug-2013", this is the code that i use for do this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dtF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtF setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *d = [dtF dateFromString:self.creationDate];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatStr = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatStr setDateFormat:@"d-MMM-yyyy"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatStr stringFromDate:d];

NSLog(@"%@",strDate);
```

This code works right, the problem is that after a few call to this method, sometimes i get a null string, but the format of the input is still the same.

For example with this string as an input "2013:07:24 11:05:04" i get this: 24-lug-2013, which is exactly what i want, but after 7 call in this case, with this input "2013:07:24 13:47:31" i get a null NSDate and consequentially the result string in null.

where is the problem??
Thanks

Comment: Give us examples of what gives you a NULL string and what doesn't.

Comment: If the code is constant and works, that leaves only the possibility that the date being returned is not conforming to the format.  Please include a live example of a date that is failing.

Comment: Yep, show us some of the values that fail.

Comment: And note that the above format uses "hh" for hours, meaning values between 1 and 12 -- 14:00:00, eg, will fail.  If you want 24-hour format use "HH".

Comment: (If you had collected enough of the successful and failing values and studied them a bit you would have noticed this distinction.)

Comment: i have add an example. thanks to all

Comment: "2013:07:24 13:47:31" -- and is 13 between 1 and 12???

Comment: @HotLicks you are totally right, the error was the "hh" instead of the "HH", i haven't thought about the difference

Comment: Even after you read my note an hour ago??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved by change this line :

```
[dtF setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss"];
```

with this:

```
[dtF setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

this is because "hh" for hours, meaning values between 1 and 12 -- 14:00:00, eg, will fail. So If you want 24-hour format use "HH"

Answer (score 2):

Date formatters return nil when the date string that is passed into them does not match the format. The code you've posted uses dateFromString on an input string. If that fails, then your NSDate "d" will be nil, and so the call to stringFromDate will likely also return nil. (Although stringFromDate might also crash if you pass in an NSDate of nil)